# How to remove some part of the URL in the address bar of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I try to remove a part of my url in the addressbar of the browser via javascript.

but I don't understand why it's not working, if I test it in the console the result is correct but it still does not change in the address bar.

How can I do it?

url I have:`http://localhost:8090/Home/Index?x=72482&success=itsdone`

url I want is:

```
http://localhost:8888/Home/Index?x=72482
```

here is my javascript code:

```
window.location.href.replace('&', '#');
window.location.hash = "";
```

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be coherent. Do you want to change & to # or to remove "&success=itsdone" ?

Comment: @dystroy:  i want to remove "&success=itsdone", in my code i have try to replace '&' to '#' and set the hase to nothing... this are a way i try it.. but yes i want to remove this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`replace` doesn't change the string on which you call it (strings are immutable), it returns a new one.

To replace `&` with `#`, do

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace('&', '#');
```

If you want to remove everything from the first `&`, the best is to use a regular expression :

```
window.location = window.location.replace(/&.*$/,'');
```

If what you want is to retain the `x` parameter, then you should rebuild the location to ensure it's still OK if the parameters are in a different order in the URL :

```
window.location = window.location.replace(/([^?]*).*(\?|&)(x=)([^&]+).*/, "$1?$3$4")
```

This changes

```
"http://localhost:8888/Home/Index?a=2&x=72482&c=3"
```

or

```
"http://localhost:8888/Home/Index?x=72482&success=itsdone"
```

into

```
"http://localhost:8888/Home/Index?x=72482"
```

Comment: you are totaly right.. thank you very much.. now i understand what was wrong all the time.

Comment: Keep in mind that most browsers will do a page reload when you change the url!

Comment: @ToBe "most" ? I think it's the required behavior if you don't just change the hash.

Comment: @dystroy I cant remember the exact browser atm, but I remeber that I had this issue in a past project. And never underestimate the users ability to keep their 10y old browser ;)

Answer (score 0):

window.location will cause a page reload. to change the port too use this

```
window.location = window.location.protocol
                + "//"
                + window.location.host
                + ":8888/"
                + window.location.pathname
                + window.location.search.substr(0, window.location.search.indexOf('&')-1)
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed the port change in the question. I suppose it's a typo (but I'm unsure).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you are passing isDone as a QueryString parameter if you do not even need it? Wouldn't it be easier to not even pass it to begin with and have the page decide if you are done?